# After updating oh-my-zsh prompt is weird on startup

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, zsh

I have been using the default installation of oh-my-zsh (robbyrussell theme) without issues. I just did a 'git pull' and now on startup I see a weird prompt. As soon as I press any key the prompt becomes normal and I can use the terminal without any issues.

I assume something in the startup script got damaged or changed when I updated or possibly the prompt config?

Here is the contents of the theme file:

```
PROMPT='%{$fg_bold[red]%}<E2><9E><9C> %{$fg_bold[green]%}%p %{$fg[cyan]%}%c %    {$fg_bold[blue]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$fg_bold[blue]%} % %{$reset_color%}'

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="git:(%{$fg[red]%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY="%{$fg[blue]%}) %{$fg[yellow]%}<E2><9C><97>%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN="%{$fg[blue]%})"
```

Comment: What do you actually see?

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled, which resolved the issue. But I was seeing sometimes one '?' sometimes multiple followed by the default cursor (solid rectangle)